# What does this string format mean: (return f"${value:,.2f}")

Tags: python, jinja2, f-string

I'm working on cs50's web track Finance Project, and in their `helpers.py` file they have the following function:

```
def usd(value):
    """Format value as USD."""
    return f"${value:,.2f}"
```

I believe that it takes a value and transforms into USD format. But in my html (using flask), I'm supposed to use it like this:

```
{{ quote["price"] | usd }}
```

Also, what does the `|` do to `quote["price"]`.
Hopefully you can help me, thanks! :)

Comment: I think you answered your own question, this is string formatting [this guide](https://thepythonguru.com/python-string-formatting/) was especially helpful when was I trying to wrap my head around the formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flask uses Jinja templates](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/) to generate the HTML.

Things in between `{{` and `}}` are expressions in Jinja and get evaluated.  You can take a value and apply a filter to it via the `|` method.

So `{{ quote["price"] | usd }}` means display the value of `quote["price"]` after applying the custom `usd` filter on the expression.

Your explanation of the `usd` filter function is accurate, it takes a number and makes sure it's display with as 2 decimal floating point.

You can read more about [Jinja expressions/variables and filters here.](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/)